# How to pass two ids for axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

My toggle switch has a axios.put that has two ids. One id is returning correctly but the other id is returning as undefined.
This is the result in console.log `'/s/groups/61/network-groups/undefined'`
This is what I want to get `'/s/groups/61/network-groups/289'`
What is the correct way to get the second 'id'?
Thanks in advance!

```js
methods{
  ...mapActions(['toggleDeliveryAction']),
        async toggleDeliveryAction( {gId, id})
        {
          let url = projConfig.apiRoot + `/s/groups/${id}/network-groups/${gId}`;
            console.log(url);
        }      
  }
```

```html
<switcher
  :value="networkGroup.isActive"
  :disabled="loading"
  @input="(isChecked) => toggleRow(isChecked, group.id, networkGroup.name, {gId: networkGroup.id})"
  />
```

Comment: you don't define actions in vue component. All you do is trigger it from the component

Comment: Aren't you overriding the ```toggleDeliveryAction``` action from your store by defining a function with the same name below ?